# How to install slingshot launcher

Tags: 11.10, installation

How to install **slingshot** launcher in ubuntu .Is there any ppa available for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementaryart/elementary-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slingshot-launcher
```

**LInks**

1. http://ubuntuguide.net/install-slingshot-elementary-os-launcher-in-ubuntu-11-04-unity
2. http://www.noobslab.com/2012/02/install-slingshot-launcher-mac-os-style.html

Comment: it is 11.04 .Is it compatable with 11.10?

Comment: The 2nd link says it is compatible with 11.10.